# how get only fields in django serializers

Tags: python, django

i used `django.core.serializers` to get data from model as below code

```
from django.core import serializers
...
serializers.serialize('json',production_time.production_items.all())
```

and i get response as below:

```
[{"model": "BorseBots.exchangemonthlyproductionitem", "pk": 1308, "fields": {'name':'jack',...}} , ...]
```

but i do not need 'model' and 'pk' fields so expect below:

```
[{'name':'jack',...} , ...]
```

or

```
[{"fields": {'name':'jack' , ...}} , ...]
```

how get this?

need use loop to extract data in new list?

using django2.2.* python3.8

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/#subset-of-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's rest framework make it possible to format your serializer as you prefer. You can extract any fields or even get values from model methods.

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import YourObject


class YourObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = YourObject
        fields = ['id', 'name', ...]
```